# Android Studio build to jar

Tags: java, android-studio

Is there a way to build Android app from Android studio to a jar file that could be run on Windows/Mac/Ubuntu? If not then why?

Comment: An Android app runs on Android, not on Windows, Mac or Linux, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Despite both is Java syntax, Oracle Java and Android Java have little in common. Gradle can certainly package JAR, but the Android classes are unknown to the regular JRE. Better use the plain [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) instead, which is rather suitable for desktop Java applications - else you could only run Android applications on an [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) or [Anbox](https://anbox.io), which isn't too portable.

Comment: What from android environment would be missing in a java environment? Would i be possible to manually include needed android libraries to build the code to a jar file. I mean the differences are not so big, as it seems to me. Would be great to build the code to android apk and also to jar file that can be run on any other platform without emulator.

Comment: @lxknvlk that "the differences are not so big" is a misconception - it's a whole different framework. Just knock it off, because you'll won't succeed with it... all you can do is port the code to Java classes known to to JRE. Anbox is the only thing which comes close to what you want to do - but it needs to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;DR** No you cannot run Android apps on Windows/Mac/Linux. Only emulators and Android devices can run them.

You should check the steps that `Gradle` performs during building before running it on the destination device.
To run on a PC (I mean Windows/Mac/Linux), you need a `jar`. And the closest thing that the build step comes to making `jar` is `javac`.

After `javac`, it performs steps to transform the java `.class` files into an Android readable format or the `dex` format and then packages the `dex`es into an `.apk`.

Android's execution environment understands `dex` and not `.class` (if it did then Android apps could have been run on all Java supported systems).

Let's say that you managed to stop after the `javac` and then managed to build a `jar`. Once you try to run it on anything other than an Android environment, you will get a ton of `NoClassDefFoundErros` because all Android specific classes are not there in the libraries in the usual JVMs (non-Android JVMs).

You should check this about the [legal dispute between Oracle and Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_v._Oracle_America). You will find that Android's Java implementation is very different that what OpenJDK offered at that time.

Comment: DEX is for Dalvik VM - ART uses OAT (pre-compiled on device from DEX files).

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes, that's right. But my idea is just for explanation purposes and doesn't dive into the details. And I think it will suffice to use it in this case as only a top level overview is enough to explain the reason.

Comment: @MartinZeitler also, the reason why I used the term `dex` is because the `Gradle` task names still use the term `dex`. That's why. Because the idea is to encourage the OP to Google for more updated information on their own and find out about the process if they want to.

Comment: There's still DEX in the APK ...just wanted to point out the change of delivery method.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, I found it a little funny when I opened up the `.apk` and found out that they were still using `.dex`. But I guess it's because of backward compatibility. And that's why maybe they translate the `.dex` into and `oat` to get native stuff that runs directly on the metal. It's good that you pointed it out. Curious audiences will be able to get the right answers faster. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I mean what if just include the needed android libraries, and build to a jar file? So that the code can be built to android apk and also to a jar file. Doesnt seem so fictional to me..

Comment: @lxknvlk you would be right to do so by including all the possible android libraries and packaging them into a jar by hook or by crook but then again, at some point of time there will be some kind of native dependency and your code will break there. Also, a lot of Java looking Android platform code will break if you run them in non-Android JVMs because that same top-level Java code has different interpretations or nothing at all in non-Android JVMs, so your code breaks there as well.